# Application Error when trying to deploy docker-compose app in azure app service

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a Django application on the azure app service using docker-compose, I already pushed two images to ACR and when I executed the docker-compose.yml on my computer everything worked fine, but when I deploy the app and visit the URL it only shows the next message:

":( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources."

I also searched in the deployment center logs for any kind of info but there is only this message

"Failed to load container logs: Resource containerlog of type text not found"

any idea how can I fix it?

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    image: zaito.azurecr.io/backgroundtasks:latest
    command: uwsgi --http "0.0.0.0:8000" --protocol uwsgi --module zaitoTasksApi.wsgi --master --processes 4 --threads 2 
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    expose:
      - "8000"
  nginx:
    image: zaito.azurecr.io/nginx:django
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  media_volume:
  static_volume:
```

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: I talked with azure support, after looking at the infraestructure the problem was that the azure app service is inside a vnet but docker-compose applications are not compatible with vnets in azure app service so I move eveything to a single Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for this error could be Azure not executing the application after a specific time limit.

The way I solved this problem is by adding the command `python app.py` in the configuration option. There is optional startup command in case the application command is not executed properly.

[image: Configuration setup screenshot]

You can enter your own application startup command.

Answer (score 0):

My response may not directly related to the initial question, but I hope the information I describe will help others too.

### Sort version

The `Container Issues` Tools from `Diagnose and solve problems` section may show error message otherwise not directly visible.

### Details

Recently we had in one of our app service the same error message even with single container.

The strange part was that it worked for two years flawless, we did not change intentionally anything.

**Initial symptoms:**
The application returns 5xx http error code
On the Deployment center / Logs page we only get the following message: **"Failed to load container logs: Resource containerlog of type text not found"**

**Recovery attempts:**
I tried start/stop the application, scale up/down the service plan, select basic/premium sku. even with stock nginx container image the app service does not provide logs.

**What we observed:**
The application returns 5xx http error code
The Development Tools / Advanced Tools returns an error page: **":( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the "**
The Development Tools / SSH return an error page: ":( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the "

**Resolution:**
Later, using the `Container Issues` Tools from `Diagnose and solve problems` section showed the following error:

> [BYOS] Custom storage volume(s) failed to initialize: [/var/LWASFiles/Sites/xxxx-d-we-001/f60654]

It turnet out, that the related storage account was recreated by terraform during a deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/955528/(-application-error-when-using-docker-compose

Looks like this issue might be with the Virtual Network Integration

"Virtual network integration isn't supported for Docker Compose scenarios in App Service."